# XMPP chat app in background - Show preview of the message in the push notification

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications, xmpp

I'm trying to connect to XMPP to show the decrypted message when the app is in background.

I'm using a notification service extension and use Darwin notification centre to connect xmpp in the main app from the extension.

Comment: It would be helpful to share the code that you use to send and handle the notifications, as well as any specific error you are getting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.